# How to make scrollable Tab Bar in IPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I m new for iphone development . Can anyOne tell me code to make scrollable Tab Bar in IPhone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

tab bar is not scrollable.. in some applications i have seen that if u have more than 5 tabs... put the 5th tab as "More" tab.. then on clicking the "More"  tab rest of the options will be shown in a table view...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u put your `UITabBar` on `UIScrollView` and in your `viewDidLoad`

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yo should follow the below link.

http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=235457

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this answer to the question below:

[Making the tab bar scrollable in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810876/making-the-tab-bar-scrollable-in-iphone)

It contains projects that use Storyboard as well as xibs.