# I need to add a tab bar in my iOS App so that user can scroll it left-right(in the bottom). Can anyone suggest how to to it?

Tags: ios

I need the tab bar to be n the bottom and scroll left right. Also if scrolled upwards it should expand as a view.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a custom tabbar. Add a scrollbar and custom buttons at the bottom.
There are few controls available.

Also you can refer this link :
[Making the tab bar scrollable in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810876/making-the-tab-bar-scrollable-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib to achieve your goal

https://github.com/Moblox/MBXPageViewController

Implement 3 method of delegate

```
- (NSArray *)MBXPageButtons
{
    return self.segmentButtons;
}

- (UIView *)MBXPageContainer
{
    return self.containerView;
}

- (NSArray *)MBXPageControllers
{
    // The order matters.
    return @[your_tabs_controllers_array];
}
```

And replace your tab bar with uiviewController with buttons on the bottom. it could save your time